# Rails app with Google Maps Javascript API only works on multiple page reloads

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to add Google Maps Javascript API to a Rails 5.2 web app. I have a Google Developer account and API key with Google Maps Javascript API enabled. There is sample code in Google's Documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. I put it in a plain html file with my API_KEY and it works fine. But I can't get it to work correctly in Rails. The three important code sections are:

1) On my html page add a div with id=map. This is where the map will be displayed.

```
# app/views/pages/map_page.html.erb
<div id="map"></div>
```

2) Call the Google API with my API key and then a callback to function initMap. I put this in the head section of the application.html.erb file.

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap" 
async defer></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

3) Define the initMap function with hard coded coordinates for the map. I put this in it's own js file.

```
# app/assets/javascripts/map.js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

This setup only works if I refresh the page one or multiple times. I am sure this is turbolinks related but if I try wrapping the function for turbolinks it makes it even worse. Then I get an error saying initMap is not a function no matter how many times I refresh the page.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
});
```

And per another SO answer I changed the Google API call in application.html.erb to the below adding data-turbolinks-eval="false. No luck.

```
<script async 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
defer data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>
```

How do I get it working without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I'll post it here in case someone comes across the same problem.

It turns out that there were two problems. One was with the CSS in the google example, which put inline is:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

This worked fine in a single html document but it didn't work in my Rails app (not sure why but apparently it's a known issue). I had to add an explicit height. The second problem is the one I called out in the question. Loading the map on the first page load without having to refresh the page. For that you need to place the Google API call and callback to the initMap function at the bottom of the page and not in the application.html.erb head section.

```
# app/views/pages/map_page.html.erb
<div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap" 
async defer></script>
```

You can put the initMap function in its own js file, or even put it in the same map_page file inside script tags above the google api call. Don't wrap it with turbolinks:load.